# Getting database error, NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I'm creating a User registration form with the AbstractBaseUser, I have got to the point where when I press "Create" on my page it should save the fields to the Database however, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\myblogsite\account\views.py", line 11, in registration_view
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 137, in save
    user.save()
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1392, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: account_account.first_name
```

I don't quite understand why it says NOT NULL constraint failed: account_account.first_name. I have nothing related to a first name field/model in my code.

Prior to getting this error, I did have the first_name field as a required field in the registration process but I deleted the field any I think I deleted everything related to it. I don't know what to do. I have tried deleted migrations and running them again and deleting the pycache.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username")

        user  = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username=username,
            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user  = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from account.forms import RegistrationForm


def registration_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: #GET request
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Finally, here is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from account.models import Account


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=60, help_text='Required. Add a valid email address')

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ("email", "username", "password1", "password2")
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not subclass `AbstractUser`, instead of `AbstractBaseUser`? The `AbstractUser` defines a `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. fields.

Comment: According to your error dump, it's the database that is complaining.  The `account` table likely still has a `first_name` column that is constrained `not null`.

Comment: You deleted your migrations?

Comment: @EdwinCruz Not the migrations folder but the migrations within the folder yes.

Comment: @MikeOrganek What do you recommend i do, i'm quite new to this sorry.

Comment: You should delete the sql lite file as well then re run your ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate``` commands

Comment: If you do not have anything you need to keep in your database, then delete your sqllite file and redo the migrations. (edit:  Just like Edwin Cruz's suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

i think when you created your project for the first time, you followed the tutorial and ran:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

because of these commands, your app make DB for django.contrib.auth.models.User (which you try to change here and build new User model).
so first of all you need to delete your db.sqlite file.
and then delete all migrations inside **migrations** folder, and delete **pycache** folders too.
but careful you must keep __init__file not deleted.
after than run those commands again and everything will be fine:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```